# Getting s3 key via boto and unicode key name

Tags: unicode, amazon-s3, boto

I am consuming a post request that refers to an s3 which may contain non-english characters such as:

```
{'key': 'náme'}
```

When the post body is loaded using json.loads it becomes:

```
{u'key': u'n\xe1me'}
```

Now unfortunately boto does not grab the object given this unicode key (I have confirmed that the object `náme` does exist in the desired bucket).

Is there a way to get the desired object via boto or do I need to look at other options such as enforcing a more boto friendly naming policy?

UPDATE:

So from what I can gather the json.loads() encoding is latin1 and simply calling `náme` in the terminal returns the utf-8 encoded version (`n\xc3\xa1me`) but I am not familiar with the encoding that boto uses when listing keys (`u'na\u0301me'`) I'm hoping that identifying that will make it easy to convert the latin1 encoding to this unknown encoding so I can begin accessing the keys when given the latin1 version from the posted data.

Comment: How does `á` get encoded in the URL?  I wonder if S3 expects percent-encoded utf8 `%C3%A1`.  Downloading the object with the console while inspecting the URL generated by the console might prove a useful exercise.

Comment: As above mentioned, S3 will show unicode key name in percent encoding using utf-8 character mapping, which is %C3%A1

Comment: Interestingly enough the did not contain `%C%A1`, but appeared as `na%CC%81me`. However boto lists the key as `u'na\u0301me.doc'` (from `s3Client.list_objects`)

Comment: This encoding method is call combining grave accent .  Honestly, I will rather ask the user save the object key as sha256 hash and put the original file name inside S3 object metadata.  Dealing with various user encoding style is almost mission impossible. Or you can enforce the method used RFC on domain name, which all name is only shown in ASCII,  all unicode will be converted with punycode converter. When you see xn- prefix, you jsut fired up the converter.